# Java - find next file in sequence

Tags: java, android

I have a directory with a number of images. Each image is in the format image-xxx.png, where xxx is a random integer (between 0 and 1million). Not all numbers are taken, so for instance it is possible to have image-1.png followed by image-27.png, etc (they're not 0 padded). Let's say I have the following files in my directory:

```
image-1.png
image-27.png
image-1511.png
image-125252.png
```

How can I find the next integer after 27 (1511) without looping through each possible integer between 28 to 1511 and checking if file.exists()?

Comment: [File#listFiles](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles()) could help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 String TAG = "MyApp"
 File file = new File("/your_directory");  
 File[] files = file.listFiles();  
 for (int fileInList = 0; fileInList < files.length; fileInList++)  
 {  
     Log.i(TAG, files[fileInList].toString());  
 }
```

This will return all files and directories in your given directory. Inside the loop, you can check the extension and filename to see if it matches your images' naming convention.

Answer (score 0):

Well the first thing you need to do is list all the files in the directory.

`File[] files = directory.listFiles();`

Then you need to order the files based on some custom comparison of their name, your implementation below.  At this point you have the files "in order" based on your rules and you do not have to increment an index.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you had a list of files you could define your own sorting order:

```
// get a collection of the filenames in the directory
List<String> filenames = Arrays.asList(new File("/path/to/directory").list());

// sort this in custom order
Collections.sort(filenames, new Comparator<String>(){
    @Override
    public int compare(String left, String right){
        String[] leftParts = left.split("[\\-\\.]");
        String[] rightParts = right.split("[\\-\\.]");

        if(leftParts.length < 3 || rightParts.length < 3){
           // filename doesn't seem to match what we expect
           // default to standard ordering
           return left.compareTo(right);
        }

        int leftVal = -1
        int rightVal = -1;
        try {
            // convert appropriate segment to integers
            leftVal = Integer.valueOf(leftParts[1]);
            rightVal = Integer.valueOf(rightParts[1]);
        } catch(NumberFormatException e) {
            return left.compareTo(right);
        }

        return rightVal - leftVal;
    }
});
```

This would let you iterate through the files in the numeric order (rather than the natural string ordering).

Answer (score 0):

Luiggi Mendoza's comment actually helped the most. I knew about listFiles but didn't realize this existed:

[File#listFiles(java.io.FilenameFilter)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles%28java.io.FilenameFilter%29)

Answer (score 0):

You can add the list of files to an `ArrayList`, then use the `indexOf` method to get the index of the specified file.  Then just increase by 1;

```
File imagesDirectory = new File("C:\\");

String[] arrayFiles;

arrayFiles = imagesDirectory.list();

ArrayList<String> listOfFiles = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(arrayFiles));

int indexOfFile = listOfFiles.indexOf("image-27.jpg");
int nextIndex = indexOfFile + 1;
```